# How to iterate two arrays in numpy/numba (zip throws error)

Tags: python, numpy, iterator, numba

I have the following code for calculating the distance of a path given a distance matrix.

```
dist_matrix = np.array(
    [
        [0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.41421356, 1.0],
        [0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.11803399, 1.11803399],
        [1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 1.41421356],
        [1.41421356, 1.11803399, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
        [1.0, 1.11803399, 1.41421356, 1.0, 0.0],
    ]
)

@jit(nopython=True)
def calc_dist(tour):
    return np.sum(np.array([dist_matrix[i, j] for i, j in zip([tour[0:-1]], tour[1:])]))

tour = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(calc_dist(tour))
```

Expected output: `2.118`

but it is throwing the following error:

````
numba.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Invalid use of Function(<intrinsic range_iter_len>) with argument(s) of type(s): (zip(iter(list(reflected list(int64))), iter(reflected list(int64))))```
````

I know I could remove the error by setting `nopython=False`, but my understanding is it's not really worth using numba unless you can use it with `nopython=True`. But I'm having trouble figuring out how to replace the `zip` in my `calc_distance` function. What's the best way to replace `zip` with numpy/numba?

Comment: There is a typo I think here: `zip([tour[0:-1]], tour[1:])` One has brackets and one doesn't. Not sure if it is relevant at all. Also might worth trying: `np.vstack((np.array(tour[0:-1]), np.array(tour[1:])))`. Seem to be working on my system but I am not a numba expert.

Answer (score 1):

If you have numpy arrays you can use **dstack():**

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
b = np.array([6,7,8,9,10])

c = np.dstack((a,b))
#or
d = np.column_stack((a,b))

>>> c
array([[[ 1,  6],
        [ 2,  7],
        [ 3,  8],
        [ 4,  9],
        [ 5, 10]]])
>>> d
array([[ 1,  6],
       [ 2,  7],
       [ 3,  8],
       [ 4,  9],
       [ 5, 10]])

>>> c.shape
(1, 5, 2)
>>> d.shape
(5, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rahul. Can you elaborate on your answer to show how you would use it to calculate `[dist_matrix[i, j] for i, j in zip([tour[0:-1]], tour[1:])]` as in my question? I've updated the question with the expected result